# Cannot install Google chrome on Windows 10

Tags: window

When I try to install Google chrome on Windows 10, the following message is being shown on screen

```
"installation failed. The Google chrome installer failed to start".
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: How's your UAC? Can you provide *any* more details?

Comment: Clear %temp% & try offline installer